# Permissions Issue when running a stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, schema, permission-denied

We are setting up a data analysis to refresh nightly and everything is working fine except for pulling the financial data from the `SERVER2` The way we have it set up is to run a stored procedure on the `SERVER1` which selects from the `SummaryView` from the `SERVER2`. We can run the stored procedure manually when we are logged in with the “admin” user. However, we cannot run it as a scheduled job. We are getting a schema lock permission on the `SummaryView`. any thoughts how to fix that?!

EDIT: Here's the error message

> Executing the query "exec financial_sp" failed with the following error: "The OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI10" for linked server "Server02" does not contain the table ""XYZ"."dbo"."SummaryView"". The table either does not exist or the current user does not have permissions on that table.". Possible failure reasons: Problems with the query, "ResultSet" property not set correctly, parameters not set correctly, or connection not established correctly.

Answer (score 1):

The user that is being used to execute the scheduled job needs execute permission on the procedure.

Comment: I tried to change that , but Sql doesn't take my updates. i think the account i am using doesn't have enough privileges. (I am logging in using the Domain admin account)

Comment: Please don't use the ADMIN account - its very, very unsafe. Create a SQL Server account that has select permission on the table(s)/view(s) involved, run BCP and put the account you just created in BCP as the user and you are on your way. You will have to do this for every SQL Server instance. If you are getting data through a stored procedure all you have to do is grant execute permission on the stored procedure to the user in BCP.

Comment: But how can i create a sql server account without the right permission . and the sql account , exists already!!

Comment: What SQL Account - Admin? Have a SQL Server admin create an account with just enough permissions to execute the stored procedure and use that account.

Comment: I just found the sa password and i changed the permission for admin to have "Execute" on that database.
The "execute" permission should be on the DB right? and not the view ? (Not sure if you can do that )

Comment: SA should have the highest level of permission on every database in the instance so you don't have to grant him or her any additional permission. Please dont use SA for this. Its like leaving the door open to your house so you don't have to fumble for keys when you get home. Its not a very good idea.

Comment: No i didnt. i just used the sa account to give permission to the sql local account "admin"